# How to copy all record from Column1 to Column2 of the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I added new column (DATE TIME) on my table and I put the same record on one column to the new column i recently added.

How can I copy all records from Column1 to Column2 of the same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do update

```
update table_name
set Column2=Column1
```